# Compile time and run time difference between type and newtype

Tags: haskell, types

What is the difference, at various stages of the read-compile-run pipeline, between a `type` declaration and a `newtype` declaration?

My assumption was that they compiled down to the same machine instructions, and that the only difference was when the program is typechecked, where for example

```
type    Name  =   String
newtype Name_ = N String
```

You can use a `Name` anywhere a `String` is required, but the typechecker will call you out if you use a `Name_` where a `String` is expected, even though they encode the same information.

I'm asking the question because, if this is the case, I don't see any reason why the following declarations shouldn't be valid:

```
type    List a  =    Either () (a, List a)
newtype List_ a = L (Either () (a, List_ a))
```

However, the type checker accepts the second one but rejects the first. Why is that?

Comment: It is not a compilation problem, it is a type checking problem.  Haskell uses "iso-recursive types" rather than "equi-recursive types", so if you want your type to be recursive you have to have a `data` or a `newtype` somewhere in there.  There are various trade-offs to each choice.  See Types and Programming Languages by Pierce for more about these systems and the choices involved.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just needed the names "iso-recursive" and "equi-recursive" to know what to Google for! If you want to convert that to an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luqui's comment should be an answer.  Type synonym's in Haskell are to first approximation nothing more than macros.  That is, they are expanded by the type checker into fully evaluated types.  The type checker can not handle infinite types, so Haskell does not have equi-recursive types.

`newtypes` provide you iso-recursive types that, in GHC, essentially compile down to equi-recursive types in the core language.  Haskell is not GHC core, so you don't have access to such types. Equi-recursive types are just a bit harder to work with both for type checkers and humans, while iso-recursive types have equivalent power.

Comment: Thanks Philip. Am I right in understanding that GHC Core has equi-recursive types, then? At what stage does the information in the `newtype` tag disappear?

Comment: I avoid core like the plague, so take everything I say with a grain of salt: GHC core has iso-recursive types.  And newtypes don't exist in core.  My belief is that this may be replaced with the use of type equality constraints in the future: so `List_ a = (Either () (a, r)) ~ r => r` with proofs of these equalities inserted at every use case (the machinery to do this already exists).

Comment: @PhilipJF: [It's a little more complicated.](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Commentary/Compiler/FC#Newtypesarecoercedtypes) Right now, newtypes compile down into a data type plus a type equality axiom: `newtype T = MkT Int` produces the axiom `axT : T ~ Int`. Unfortunately, this is unsound: if we have `type family F a ; type instance F Int = Bool ; type instance F T = Char`, then `Bool ~ F Int`, `F Int ~ F T`, and `F T ~ Char`.  Thus `Bool ~ Char`, and we're in trouble. [This can actually be tickled with `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`.](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/1496)

Comment: @AntalS-Z `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` is unsound regardless of how `newtypes` are  compiled.  Some instances simply cannot be "newtype derived" safely no matter how you do it.  I have been of the opinion for a while (and [blogged](http://joyoftypes.blogspot.com/2012/08/generalizednewtypederiving-is.html) about it) that `GeneralizedNewtypedDeriving` should either be scraped or replaced with a process that generates code and retype checks it respecting module boundries--that is, `GeneralizedNewtypedDeriving` should be able to fail!

Comment: @PhilipJF: Absolutely! I was, though, trying to make a weaker point.  There's this unsoundness at the Core/System FC level in how newtypes are compiled, but (AFAIK) source Haskell can't trigger it—*unless* you use `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving`. (I had, admittedly, forgotten that GND had other problems.) If you solved the Core-/System FC-level unsoundness ([Stephanie Weirich *et al.* have a 2011 paper which does](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~sweirich/papers/popl163af-weirich.pdf), although it's unimplemented), you would no longer be able to write `coerce :: a -> b`. (But modules are separate.)